# C# compile error: "No logical space left to create more user strings"

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to compile a one-off "script", an autogenerated C# program. This program contains 120,000 different string literals. The C# compiler can't build this, saying:

```
Unexpected error writing metadata to file '<removed>' -- 'No logical space left to create more user strings.'
```

Is there a hard limit in .NET on the number of string literals one can have in a module? What is this limit? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Man, this sounds like a bad idea all around.

Comment: As Raymond Chen once put it, "if you have to ask [about limits], you're probably doing something wrong" : http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you might need to rethink you're architecture... Why would you need so many string literals? Are you storing a dictionary in code or something?

Comment: Heh, I totally agree with all your comments. But this was a "one-off" chunk of code that I have already run and deleted forever, so no architecture rethinking is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of strings in an assembly, just as there are limits on the number of classes, fields, etc. Each of these is identified with a 32-bit [metadata token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404456.aspx), where the upper-most byte is a meta-type-code, and the lower bits are the individual data record. For strings, they actually identify an offset into the string heap, so you can have at most 2**24 bytes for strings, i.e. 16MiB. Not sure whether strings are stored in UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: The entire source file is 14 MiB in UTF-8, so if they are stored in UTF-16 the limit will be exceeded. Makes sense!

Comment: A workaround could be to retrieve the string from resource streams.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea of what the limits are in .NET but, if it is a resource limitation, I'd solve it the same way we solved running out of space in the bad old 64K-segment days.

Externalize the strings - put them in an external file and simply store the offsets (and lengths if they're not null terminated). When you need a string, load it from the file and use it.

Comment: Rather than just tackling the outcome, I would look into what the compiler error means first. The MSDN page given by Dreas and myself suggests that this could be a DLL conflict or a disk space problem rather than anything to do with fixed limits on the number of strings.

Comment: Yes, but the phrase "contains 120,000 different string literals" seems to point to an actual resource problem rather than a naming problem. And I made sure I stated "if it is a resource limitation". I don't know for sure, just offering advice on how to get around it. I suspect that's at least as useful as someone parroting the first thing they found by entering the error into Google :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've never encountered this before myself, but there is some information and suggested solutions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b29s6et.aspx)

However, unless you have a good reason for using hard coded string literals, you should probably consider using resource files rather than literals for most strings.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. I doubt it's a broken install. The error message says quite clearly that there are too many strings, and indeed, 120,000 strings is a LOT of strings :)

Comment: The page also suggests a problem with a conflict between dll names. (Check the community content at the bottom)