# No logical space left to create more user strings. [ MVC PRECOMPILE ]

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller, view, precompile

We are generating MVC views as a pre-compiled dll. But due to our application growth we getting the below error.

> No logical space left to create more user strings.

While generating a pre-compiled dll the class will have N number string literals. Is there is any solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the number of strings you can define in an assembly.
I guess splitting dll with views into multiple dlls could be the solution

Here is info about this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362635/c-sharp-compile-error-no-logical-space-left-to-create-more-user-strings)